# Prevent Jenkins from starting build when referenced Git repo changes

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins multibranch pipeline and two Git repos:

Repo 1 - Git webhook enabled. Configured as "Branch Source" for the pipeline, with filter, so only some branches are built and others are excluded.

Repo 2 - No webhook. Contains a tool that is cloned during the build process with the following code in the Jenkinsfile:

```
checkout(poll:false, changelog: false, scm:[$class: 'GitSCM',
                      branches: [[name: "master"]],
                      doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                      extensions: [[$class: 'GitLFSPull'], [$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: false, reference: '', shallow: true]],
                      submoduleCfg: [],
```

When a new commit is pushed to Repo 1, to one of the *excluded* branches, the webhook is executed (as expected), but then Jenkins checks for changes in both Repo 1 and Repo 2.

If Repo 2 has changes, it will start a build on one of the *included* branches on Repo 1, even though that branch has no changes.

How can I prevent changes to Repo 2 from starting any builds?